# Joomla full article

Tags: php, joomla, menu

I had a blog on the home page of my Joomla website. I decided to move it to the link "home/news"( on bosnian language "/pocetna/novosti"). Now I have a problem that I can not open the full article.
So, before the blog was on https://bascarsija.info, and now is on https://bascarsija.info/pocetna/novosti. I can open blog and intro articles, but  when I try to open the full article at the link missing menu and category name so I have empty page.
The link should be: bascarsija.info/pocetna/novosti/some-article
And now is without menu and category name: bascarsija.info/some-article

When I manually add: /pocetna/novosti everything is OK

My cash is turned off, I tried reinstalling Joomla, but the problem is not solved. I checked in the database menu path is correct (/pocetna/novosti)

Hoe can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

How you publish your articles in Novosti page? Maybe the problem is there. Try to use Joomla native content component.

Try also to view the website using the default Joomla template (protostar) to avoid any overrides of the Joomla content component.